# Comparative Statics on Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

Let me first explain what I am doing then I will mention my little problem that I could not figure out. I am using Mathematica version 7. I have an equation named "***fd***" and I took the derivative of "***fd***" with respect to ***t*** which I will note the outcome as ***Dfdt***. Basically, I am trying to understand if ***Dfdt*** is negative or positive (Comparative Statics) and in order to do this I put some assumptions on the parameters in the simplify function which will be seen in my code below. However, as a outcome I get a general restriction outcome which satisfies ***Dfdt*** being positive or negative. Are there any possible methods/codes to take out the parameters values which satisfies ***Dfdt*** being positive or negative ?

```
      In[54]:=
      Remove["Global`*"]
      q = 1 - p;
      fd = (b d (p - q) Y1 Y2 (p Y1 - q Y2) + 
      a p q t (Y1 + Y2)^2 (p (-1 + Y1^2) Y2 + 
      q Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)))/(a p q t (Y1 + Y2)^2 (p (-1 + Y1^2) Y2 + 
      q Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)));
      Dfdt = D[fd, t]
      Simplify[Dfdt > 0,  Y2 > Y1 > 0 && t > 0 && 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0 && 1 > d > 0    
      && 1 > p > 0 ]
      Simplify[Dfdt < 0,  Y2 > Y1 > 0 && t > 0 && 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0 && 1 > d > 0    
      && 1 > p > 0 ]


      Out[55]:= 1/t - (b d (-1 + 2 p) Y1 Y2 (p Y1 - (1 - p) Y2) + 
      a (1 - p) p t (Y1 + Y2)^2 (p (-1 + Y1^2) Y2 + (1 - p) Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)))/(a (1 - p) p t^2 (Y1 
      + Y2)^2 (p (-1 + Y1^2) Y2 + (1 - p) Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)))   

      Out[56]:= (-1 + 2 p) (-Y2 + p (Y1 + Y2)) (p Y2 - p Y1^2 Y2 + (-1 + p) Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)) > 0
      Out[57]:= (-1 + 2 p) (-Y2 + p (Y1 + Y2)) (p Y2 - p Y1^2 Y2 + (-1 + p) Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)) < 0
```

Comment: You could try Reduce: `Reduce[{Dfdt > 0, 
  Y2 > Y1 > 0 && t > 0 && 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0 && 1 > d > 0 && 
   1 > p > 0}]` and `Reduce[{Dfdt < 0, 
  Y2 > Y1 > 0 && t > 0 && 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0 && 1 > d > 0 && 
   1 > p > 0}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simplification noting that your `fd` is a fraction and therefore its derivative is a fraction with a squared denominator, which is always positive and need not be considered. My proposal is to calculate the derivative "by hand".

```
expr = FullSimplify[fd];
Dexprdt = Simplify[D[Numerator[expr], t] Denominator[expr] - 
                   Numerator[expr] D[Denominator[expr], t]];
```

The solution for positive values is then :

```
solPos = LogicalExpand[Reduce[Dexprdt > 0, Reals]];
solPos // Dimensions
(* {2576} *)
```

Check solution 1 and 2001 say :

```
N[Dexprdt] /. First@FindInstance[solPos[[1]], {Y1, Y2, a, b, d, p}]
(* 5.59992*10^11 *)

N[Dexprdt] /. First@FindInstance[solPos[[2001]], {Y1, Y2, a, b, d, p}]
(* 0.255154 *)
```

Compare the above two lines to using your original function though :

```
FullSimplify[N[Dfdt] /. First@FindInstance[solPos[[1]], {Y1, Y2, a, b, d, p}]]
(* (0.301644 + 2.22045*10^-16 t)/t^2 *)
```

This can be negative for extremely large (and negative) `t`; if it makes sense, you can apply `Chop` to get rid of the small number.

The other seems ok :

```
FullSimplify[N[Dfdt] /. First@FindInstance[solPos[[2001]], {Y1, Y2, a, b, d, p}]]
(* 3.58048/t^2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a really helpful answer. I have one question, when you obtain a numeric solution "N[Dexprdt]" for solPos[1] = (Y1 == -1 && Y2 == -(1/Sqrt[2]) && a > 0 && b > 0 && d > 0 && p > 1) the system only substitutes a value of a,b,d and p which makes the system positive, right? Or does it also satisfy that for all values of a,b,d > 0 && p > 1 given Y1==-1 && Y2 == -(1/Sqrt[2]) it is positive ?

Comment: And since it has 2576 solutions are there any possible ways that I can only choose the solutions where p is greater than 0 in the logical expand without checking all 2576 solutions by hand ?

Comment: @HarveyMudd The solution is generic, so you get inequalities; I wanted to make a quick check so I used `FindInstance` to pick one particular choice of `solPos[[1]]` say.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a different question related with this problem about extracting the positive set of solutions and I asked in a different title since people who have problems regarding the issue will get an idea under that title. Thanks again for a very useful answer.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26470/selecting-possible-solutions-in-logical-expand