# Extract Positive Solutions in Logical Expand

Tags: symbolic

I am using Mathematica version 7. I have an expression named `fd` and I took the derivative of `fd` with respect to `t` which I will note the outcome as `Dexprdt`. Basically, I am trying to understand if `Dexprdt` is negative or positive (Comparative Statics) and in order to do this I have the following set-up which was proposed here by b.gatessucks and it works really well. `solPos` shows the logical expansion which makes `Dexprdt` positive. However, as seen in the below code there are 2576 possible combination of solutions and I only want to extract the solutions (inequalites) where `Y1`, `Y2`, `a`, `b`, `d`, `p` are **positive reals**. I tried to use `Pick` command and it was not really useful. I really need help with the methodology. Here is the code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
q = 1 - p;
fd = (b d (p - q) Y1 Y2 (p Y1 - q Y2) + a p q t (Y1 + Y2)^2 (p (-1 + Y1^2) Y2 + 
q Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)))/(a p q t (Y1 + Y2)^2 (p (-1 + Y1^2) Y2 + q Y1 (-1 + Y2^2)));
expr = FullSimplify[fd];
Dexprdt = Simplify[D[Numerator[expr], t] Denominator[expr] - 
Numerator[expr] D[Denominator[expr], t]];
(*Normally in Dexprdt we should have D[Denominator[expr]^2 dividing \
but since it is always positive it is enough to check the Numerator \
of the derivative*)

solPos = LogicalExpand[Reduce[Dexprdt > 0, Reals]]
(*solPos is the possible solutions that makes Dexprdt positive*)

solPos // Dimensions;
(*{2576} - number of possible solutions*)

(*N[Dexprdt]/.First@FindInstance[solPos[[1]],{Y1,Y2,a,b,d,p}]*)
(*5.59992*10^11*)
```

Comment: Your definition of Dexprdt is strange. It seems you have forgotten a `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Temporary: The observations here were made by adding an extra D in the expression for Dexprdt.*

Well, you could just do

```
solPos2 = 
 LogicalExpand[
  Reduce[Dexprdt > 0 && Y1 > 0 && Y2 > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0 && d > 0 &&
     p > 0, Reals]]
```

This gives you a much smaller expression. However, I would guess that there are infinitely many solutions. Note that many (if not all) of the alternatives in `solPos` contain inequalities, and only one of these alternatives has to be true for your inputs in order for `solPos` to be true. So there are infinitely many solutions. So you cannot put their numerical values into a list or something like that.